# writing an array to h5 in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, h5py

Using the h5py module I'm trying to simply read in data from one h5 file, do some basic calculations with the data and write it back into a new h5 file. All is well, except when trying to write the dataset.

so far I have:

```
f = h5py.File(inData,'r')
dset = f['/DATA/DATA/']
HH = dset[...,0]

HHdB = (10*numpy.log10(HH*HH)) - 83

outfile = h5py.File(outData, 'w')
f.create_dataset('/DATA/DATA/', data=(HHdB))
```

This returns me the error: "ValueError: unable to create dataset (Dataset: Unable to initialize object)", which I don't understand.

Im a newbie so any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`f.create_dataset` should be `outfile.create_dataset`, since `f` is the `File` opened in read mode, while `outfile` is a `File` opened in write mode.

By the way, if you use the `h5py.File`s as a context manager in a [with-statement](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm),
the file will automatically be closed for you (and written to disk) when Python leaves the with-statement.

```
import numpy
import h5py

with h5py.File(inData,'r') as f:
    dset = f['/DATA/DATA/']

HH = dset[...,0]
HHdB = (10*numpy.log10(HH*HH)) - 83

with h5py.File(outData, 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.create_dataset('/DATA/DATA/', data=HHdB)
```

Comment: Well thats embarrassing. It was some code I copied from somewhere else and I forgot to change it. Thanks for the help (and for not laughing at me)!

Comment: was going to mention the with-statement, though on some older machines (at work or so), this might not yet work (with-statement was introduced in python 2.5)